# How to output a relationship field within a grid field?

Tags: relationships, grid

This pdf contains my question with screenshots: http://swmc.online/speakername.pdf

I am building a very simple conference website. Each year there is a conference. Each conference contains different speakers.

I have a **speakers** channel.
I have a **conferences** channel.

The conferences channel contains a field group named **conferences**

The conferences field group contains a grid named: **teachings**

The grid contains a relationship field named: **speaker**

When adding conferences I select the **speaker** from the relationship field

I want the selected speaker’s name to appear in the conference listing page
http://swmc.online/index.php/home/speakername

How can I pull the two fields **{first_name}** **{last_name}** from the **speakers** channel field group named **speakers**  within the Conferences tag pair?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

  `{teachings:speaker}
    {teachings:speaker:first_name}
    {teachings:speaker:last_name}
  {/teachings:speaker}`

Comment: Michael,

Thank you for your response. Your solution pulled the speaker's names but all of the names instead of the selected speaker.

Additionally, it eliminated all the other data. 

See highlights in this screenshot.
http://swmc.online/capture.jpg

Any more guidance would be wonderful!

Comment: Michael! Thank you! I figured it out based upon what you provided.

The solution is to eliminate the {teachings}{/teachings} tag pair.

This is working solution:

{teachings:speaker}{teachings:speaker:first_name} {teachings:speaker:last_name}{/teachings:speaker}

Comment: Thank you so very much, Michael! I greatly appreciate you!

Comment: Not a problem!!